How do I match a list number to it's list ID number? (TI 84 Plus CE)
I made an attempt to solve a calculus problem that I was presented (I do not remember the specifics), and I needed to basically work backwards from the L1 (1) = -3. I need something that I can input that -3 and it would return 1, and would work for all other similar cases. The L1 is populated with the values {-3,0,3,4} and I would like to put each of those in and get back {1,2,3,4} with each input, and I do not want to use a program.
So far I have tried using a program, but it doesn't work for the application that I am trying to use it for. I simply can't type it into an equation like I can do with L1(1) and get the value -3.
